# How can I left align a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a pie chart with a left aligned title:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set_title('Pie Title', loc='left')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(r'C:\images\pie.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

And this code produces this image:

[image: Pie Chart]

But there's too much whitespace around the pie chart.  How can I left align the title and pie chart and crop the unnecessary whitespace?

[image: Left Align Pie Chart]

Comment: You can also save a transparent figure with 'plt.savefig(transparent=True)' (I know its not the question but the "..crop the unnecessary whitespace" reminded me of it)

Answer (score 3):

You can start off with a square figure, e.g. `figsize=(4,4)`.
You can then add some whitespaces to have the title aligned.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax1.pie(sizes, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set_title('  Pie Title', loc='left')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(__file__+"pie.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If this isn't enough whitespace clearance, you can play around with `subplots_adjust`, like `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, top=0.93, left=0.0, right=1)`.

Comment: `fig1.subplots_adjust(left=0.2,wspace = 0.2)` works great!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can move set_title in other ways than center, left or right. What you can do instead is adding text like this:

```
ax1.text(-0.8, 1, 'Pie Title')
```

See the documentation here on how to change font and so on: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html